# How can I add media breakpoints to this jquery script?

Tags: jquery

I use the following script to make the background of my website change automatically. However, I want a different background to appear after a certain width.

I am still quite inexperienced when it comes to jquery and javascript in general, so I need help with this.

How can I use multiple breakpoints in this script?

```
jQuery(function ($) {
 

   function changeColor(selector, colors, time) {
        /* Params:
         * selector: string,
         * colors: array of color strings,
         * every: integer (in mili-seconds)
         */
        var curCol = 0,
            timer = setInterval(function () {
                if (curCol === colors.length) curCol = 0;
                $(selector).css("background", colors[curCol]);
                curCol++;
            }, time);
    }
    $(window).load(function () {
        changeColor("#shop .container", ["url(c-l-s.png) no-repeat","url(c-w-s.png) no-repeat", "url(c-m-s.png) no-repeat", "url(c-b-s.png) no-repeat"], 5000);
    });
});
```

I need something like:

> If width 1023px then

```
$(window).load(function () {
    changeColor("#shop .container", ["url(c-l.png) no-repeat","url(c-w.png) no-repeat", "url(c-m.png) no-repeat", "url(c-b.png) no-repeat"], 5000);
});
```

So far I have considered solving the problem by hiding a div and displaying a new one starting at 1023 px wide. However, I would then have a double content, which is not the most optimal way in my opinion. Nevertheless, I would have the same result.

Comment: You can use `$(document).width();` - see [width() documentation](https://api.jquery.com/width/). How you do this is up to you. You can even create a working snippet with the `<>` button. Use [picsum.photos](https://picsum.photos/) for example images.

Comment: I have tried $(window).width(1023px).load(function () but its not working. Could you create an example maybe?

Comment: If you write this: `$(window).width(1023px)` jQuery tries to set the width value. You don't want to set the width, you want to get the width. Call without parameters. As the answer points out: `$(document).width() < 1023` for example compares the body's width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem as follows: I placed two containers on top of each other and did not display the second one. From a width of 1023 px the first is hidden and the second is shown. A third container with the text lies over both containers and is always displayed. So I could avoid duplicate content and still implement my idea.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the title of your question, in your javascript, you can add `debugger;` -- when you view the Developer Console and the breakpoint is hit, you'll be able to step through and debug each step.

Like so:

[image]

When this runs in the browser, it looks like this:

[image]

Alternatively, in your Developer Console, find the code you want to debug and click in the gutter -- you'll see a breakpoint added. It'll look like so:

[image]

... and when the breakpoint is hit, again, it'll look like this:

[image]

I hope this helps with your debugging!

Comment: sorry but this somehow doesn't helps me

Comment: You're talking about `media breakpoints` not `debugging breakpoints` -- my bad :)

Comment: no, my bad. fixed the title and thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

You could add an event listener, like so:

```js
$(window).on("load", () => {
    window.colIndex = 0;
    window.timer = null;

    function changeColor(selector, colors, time) {
        /* Params:
         * selector: string,
         * colors: array of color strings,
         * every: integer (in mili-seconds)
         */
        if ( window.timer !== null )
            clearInterval(window.timer);
        window.timer = setInterval(() => {
            if (window.colIndex === colors.length) 
                window.colIndex = 0;
            $(selector).css("background", colors[window.colIndex]);
            window.colIndex += 1;
        }, time);
    }

    $(window).on("resize", () => {
        const images = $(document).width() < 1023 ? ["url(c-l.png) no-repeat","url(c-w.png) no-repeat", "url(c-m.png) no-repeat", "url(c-b.png) no-repeat"] : ["url(c-l.png) no-repeat","url(c-w.png) no-repeat", "url(c-m.png) no-repeat", "url(c-b.png) no-repeat"];
        changeColor("#shop .container", images, 5000);
    });
});
```

We create an event listener on the window resize event, after the window has loaded. We store the current colour index and the timer on the window object so we don't trip over ourselves every time the Resize event is hit.

This is just using a [turnery operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) so, if the document width is less than 1023 then use `"url(c-l.png) no-repeat","url(c-w.png) no-repeat", "url(c-m.png) no-repeat", "url(c-b.png) no-repeat"]` otherwise, use `["url(c-l.png) no-repeat","url(c-w.png) no-repeat", "url(c-m.png) no-repeat", "url(c-b.png) no-repeat"]`

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried it but unfortunately it did not work. I am looking for a solution because the images fit for the desktop but no longer on the mobile version. I can not think of a better solution than to use other images from a width of 1023 px. But thank you very much.

Comment: I see the flaw with the code too, with not resetting the interval. Let me update the answer.